# RabbitMQ basicpublish and basicget unequal performance

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm learning to code and administer RabbitMQ.  Using BasicPublish, I can average 2,500msg/sec, using 16 byte messages.  Sometimes its as high as 5,000msgs/sec.  Using BasicGet,the performance is 45msg/sec steady.  If I use BasicConsume with a QueueingBasicConsumer, the performance between BasicPublish and BasicConsume is roughly equal, but I do not get every message I send.  If I consume with noAck=false, and then call BasicAck(msg.uDeliveryTag), BasicPublish can be 2,500msg/sec, BasicConsume the same, and Acknowledgment 8msg/sec?  What gives?  It wasnt always like this; performance was roughly equal at 800msg/sec, but it's bad now.  HELP?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, probably, you've already seen this links, if no, give it a look: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Meanwhile, as of written, this question tends to be offtopic for SO because it doesn't include any details about environment where the problem happen and doesn't show (or point to) any code which cause specific trouble. Also it is unclear what did you expect and why.

Comment: What details can I add to make it on topic?  I install RabbitMQ 3.5.4 on Windows and Fedora and am writing a test client to publish/get the message.  I wrote the client in C# and the basic gist of everything is this:

Comment: connect to RabbitMQ
create channel
declare queue
iterate 65536 times
    BasicPublish msg to channel on server
do
   BasicGet msg from channel on server
while(msg != null)